# Android Gradle logger does not accept java.lang.String

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I'm trying to put some log messages in my `build.gradle` file:

```
android { 
    ...
    ...

    buildTypes {
        ...
        ...

        applicationVariants.all { variant ->                
            logger.warn('A warning log message.')
        }
    }
}
```

I'm led to understand, by [this Gradle doc](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/logging.html), that there is just a static `logger` available to be called whenever. In fact, that `logger.warn()` bit is copied straight out of that doc. However, I get this message:

```
No signature of method: com.android.build.gradle.internal.LoggerWrapper.warn() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [A warning log message.]
```

It seems odd to me that `logger.warn()` and all of its other equivalents (error, info, etc) do not accept Strings as input. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like because you are in the closure that configures the `android` object, the reference to `logger` is resolved as the internal Android logger object.

I would use `project.logger...` everywhere to make sure you access the default Gradle logger.

The internal Android logger is defined here: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/base/+/master/common/src/main/java/com/android/utils/ILogger.java

Comment: Thanks very much. Per the provided definition, logger.warning("string") also works.

Comment: I would use the Gradle logger instead of ours since ours is "private" and may change name (or actually become private) at any time.